# Как вывести текст с тегами в Angular?

Tags: angularstrap, angularjs

Как вывести текст с тегами в Angular на страницу?
Сейчас это работает как: `<b>text</b>` вместо **text**

Comment: Вы уверены, что именно, когда подключили ангулар-это пропало? Или Вы хотите из скрипта вывести html?

Comment: В переменную `$scope.text = '<b>text</b>';` заносится текст с тегами. Эта самая переменная выводится на странице как '<b>text</b>'

Comment: И возможно ли в angular для 2-х контроллеров описать отдельный общие функции и вынести их за пределы контроллера?

Comment: В ангуляре есть директивы. Ну типа считается правилом хорошего тона,  если вы хотите вставить кусок кода - использовать их. И ещё посмотрите ng-class. Может подключать на лету класс. Ещё есть ng-show /ng-hide если хотите отобразить/скрыть что-либо

Comment: Для того, чтоб создать какой либо общий функционал для нескольких контроллерв, в angular существуют [сервисы][1]. Они там разные бывают, [тут][2] хорошо описаны различия.


  [1]: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services
  [2]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/190342/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml), только не забудьте подключить angular-sanitize.js

Comment: Да, но `ng-bind-html`не получается использоваться для такой конструкции:

`<div class="form-error"  ng-repeat="error in messages" ng-show="response.type === 'error'">
{{error}}
</div>`

Comment: почему не получится?

Comment: Потому как я документации описано, вывод проиcходит так:

`<div class="form-error" ng-bind-html="response.messages"></div>`, где `response.messages` - строковая переменная. А у меня это массив

Comment: А зачем вы пытаетесь выводить массив да еще и с сохранением HTML?

Comment: А, понял. Вы можете написать так:

    <div ng-repeat="error in messages" ng-bind-html="error">{{ error }}</div>

Answer (score 2):

**попробуйте использовать $sce сервис**

```
$scope.text = sce.trustAsHtml('<b>text</b>');
```

**шаблон:**

```
ng-bind-html="text"
```

Answer (score -2):

А не легче сделать так?

```
<b>{{TEXT}}</b>
--------------
```

А обычный вариант что не работает? Если сперва в скопе задаёте с тегом, как вы указали, а потом пишите в html

```
<div>{{text}}</div>
```

Не проверяю сейчас, но, по идее, должно работать.

P.S. НЕ ЗАБУДЬТЕ указать ng-app вначале и контроллер, а то может этого нет.

Comment: Отлично - ещё и минусуют. Ну спасибо. Дыбилы какие-то минусуют. Мне пох-всёравно рейтинг высокий. Наверное ж не из за того что я бред пишу на сайте

Comment: @Роман Ракзин ТС как раз таки и хотел избавиться от плейсхолдеров `{{...}}`. Скорее всего, чтобы избежать моргания (появление на мгновение плейсхолдеров) при рендеринге страницы.

Comment: ng-cloak вроде убирает моргание. Ну либо поставить ng-show или ng-class когда загрузится....как-то так

Comment: Я думаю, что все-таки имеется в виду, что HTML может быть не только как в примере, а например, "Стоимость <b>23</b> руб" или "Стоимость&nbsp;23&nbsp;руб", и все это должно корректно отобразиться. Если же нет и там только обрамляющий тег, то ТС и правда должен от него избавиться и перенести в шаблон.